# Laravel sessions with sweet alert Session Loops

Tags: php, session, laravel-5, sweetalert

I'm just confused about my code. But I really thought that my code is correct. I'm trying to use `with()` method in Laravel 5.1 and then return to a view, then the sweet alert appears if the session that has been set is exists. Please see my code below:

**PageController.php**

```
return redirect()->route('list.view')->with('sweetalert', 'List has been created!');
```

**view.blade.php**

```
@extends('layout.master')

@section('container')
  @foreach($lists as $list)
    <li>{{ $list->name }}</li>
  @endforeach
@stop
```

**master.blade.php**

```
<div class="container">
  // some markup here...
</div>

@if(Session::has('sweetalert'))
<script>
    swal('Success!', '{{ Session::get('sweetalert') }}', 'success');
</script>
@endif
```

I only want it to appear once, but if I try to click the back button, the message appears again. I have also tried the ff. code but nothings change:

```
@if(Session::has('sweet'))
  <script>
      swal('Success!', '{{ Session::get('sweetalert') }}', 'success');
  </script>
  <?php Session::forget('sweetalert'); ?>
@endif
```

Little help here?

Comment: Instead of passing the session in with() directly I would suggest using session()->flash() and declaring the key here and then pass it in with().

Comment: @DhavalChheda May you write an answer explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

a flash message has to be trigerred otherwise it will not make sense as you will set it everytime for the view

however you can use this code wherever the trigger is

Please Note :- I am just trigerring it everytime

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    session()->flash('testing', 'I see this'); // Please have this line inside the trigger so the session does not get created everytime the view is called
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Still the same bro. Hm maybe its because of the sweet alert? what do you think bro?